# I want fill five years in a drop-down using javascript and the years will be after the current years

Tags: javascript

I want fill five years in a drop-down using javascript and the years will be after the current year.

for example:

if current year is 2012 then the drop-down values are 2012,2013,2014,2015,2016

Comment: Create a date object, get the year, increment it as required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML

```
<form id="someform">
<select id="year"></select>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var myselect = document.getElementById("year"), year = new Date().getFullYear();
var gen = function(max){do{myselect.add(new Option(year++,max--),null);}while(max>0);}(5);
```

A little bit better JavaScript function:

```
var myselect = document.getElementById("year"),
    startYear = new Date().getFullYear()
    count = 5;

(function(select, val, count) {
  do {
    select.add(new Option(val++, count--), null);
  } while (count);
})(myselect, startYear, count);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHSWK/), [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHSWK/238/)

Answer (score 6):

You could get the list of years like so...

```
var date = new Date,
    years = [],
    year = date.getFullYear();

for (var i = year; i < year + 5; i++) {
   years.push(i);   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/GnsdZ/).

Or to actually create your `select` element...

```
var date = new Date,
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    select = document.createElement('select');

for (var i = year; i < year + 5; i++) {

    var option = document.createElement('option'),
        yearText = document.createTextNode(i);

    option.appendChild(yearText);
    select.add(option);   
}

select.name = 'year';

document.body.appendChild(select);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/LPRaw/).

Comment: `var date = new Date,` should be `var date = new Date(),` since it's an invocation of a constructor.

Comment: @IsaacGregson It *could* be, but it's not required.

Answer (score 4):

If you use jQuery, the task can be achieved as follow:

```
   var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();  

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
        $("#timeSelector").append(

            $("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", currentYear)
                .text(currentYear)

        );
        currentYear++;
    }
```

View demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fP4cX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(); 
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            $("#years").append(
               $('<option/>')
               .attr("value", currentYear + i)
               .text(currentYear + i));
        }
```