# Jquery select option and get value on change working only once (on page load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I have select fields for birth date and want to put some limits **based on selection**.

**So, I have dropdown list of options for all select fields.**

If someone selects 2010 as year then months from 9-12 should be disabled. However I am stuck since I cannot get script to load values for year every time you make selection. It only fires on page load **and when I make selection for year nothing happens and it should output "alert" (in my example).**

SELECT:

```
<select name="student_birth_year[]" class="birth_year">
    <option>1900</option>
    <option>1901</option>
    <option>1902</option>
    <option>....</option>
    <option>2010</option>
</select>
<select name="student_birth_month[]" class="birth_month">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>12</option>
</select>
<select name="student_birth_day[]" class="birth_day">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>31</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.s_dob').on("change", ".birth_year" , function() {
    var birth_year=$(this).val();
        alert( this.value );
    if(birth_year==2010){
        $('.birth_month option').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not entirely clear what is or isn't happening.

Comment: change not working ?

Comment: A little unclear, but you wrote "script to load values" and "only fires on page load" - I think you are doing something with drop-down, and the issue is probably related to the disabling / clearing the values inside. In that case your drop-down is populated only once when the page is loaded, afterwards it is not populated again.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to generate the select, and regenerate every time - something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274417/i-want-fill-five-years-in-a-drop-down-using-javascript-and-the-years-will-be-aft) an configure the function with PHP.

Comment: Ok, I have elaborated my problem. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into some problems while using simple select elements, because different months have different amount of days. Consider using ready solution: [Combodate](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/).

Unfortunately, Combodate doesn't have disable API abilities. But you can always do it using jQuery:

```
$('.combodate').on("change", ".year-select" , function() {
  var year = $(this).val();
  if(parseInt(year)===2010){
    for(i = 9; i <= 12; i++) {
      $('.combodate .month-select option[value="'+i+'"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  }else{
     $('combodate .month-select option').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```